# Проверка элемента на целостность Java

Tags: java

Есть задача

Создайте два массива из 10 целых случайных чисел из отрезка [1;9] и третий массив из 10 действительных чисел. Каждый элемент с i-ым индексом третьего массива должен равняться отношению элемента из первого массива с i-ым индексом к элементу из второго массива с i-ым индексом. Вывести все три массива на экран (каждый на отдельной строке), затем вывести количество целых элементов в третьем массиве.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] massivOne = new int[10];
    int[] massivTwo = new int[10];
    double[] massivThree = new double[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        massivOne[i] = (int)(Math.random()*8 +1);
        massivTwo[i] = (int)(Math.random()*8 +1);
        massivThree[i]= massivOne[i]/massivTwo[i];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        System.out.print(massivOne[i] + " ");

    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        System.out.print(massivTwo[i] + " ");

    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        System.out.print(massivThree[i] + " ");

    }

    System.out.println();

}
```

}

ни могу никак сообразить, как правильно проверить на целостность? и вообще правильно ли остальное решение? заранее спасибо за подсказку:)

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.sevak_avet.Test;

import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[10];
    int[] b = new int[10];
    double[] c = new double[10];

    Random r = new Random();
    int wholeCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        a[i] = 1 + r.nextInt(9);
        b[i] = 1 + r.nextInt(9);
        c[i] = a[i] / (double) b[i];

        if (c[i] == (int) c[i]) {
            ++wholeCount;
        }
    }

    for (int number : a) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", number);
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int number : b) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", number);
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (double number : c) {
        if (number == (int) number) {
            System.out.printf("(%.2f) ", number);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%.2f ", number);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Count: " + wholeCount);

}
```

}